# Grunt: including a generated file in usemin

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

This is the relevant part in my `index.html`:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/ember.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/neuterapp.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

(but the last two entrires are wrong, that is actually my problem)

This is the relevant part of the `Gruntfile.js`:

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/*.css'],
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
    },
```

The problem that I have is that both `templates.js` and `neuterapp.js` are generated files, so they are not in `<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts`, but in `<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts`.

This is my (simplified) directory structure:

```
webapp/
├── app
│   ├── app.js <--- for neuter
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── models
│   ├── routes
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── vendor <--- for usemin
│   ├── templates <--- for ember_templates
│   │   ├── template1.hbs
│   │   └── template2.hbs
│   └── views
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── scripts
│       ├── neuterapp.js <--- this must also be used for usemin!!!
│       └── templates.js <--- this must also be used for usemin!!!
└── Gruntfile.js
```

How can I tell `usemin` to include some generated files?

And in case this is needed, these are the configurations of `neuter` and `ember_templates`:

```
    neuter: {
        options: {
            includeSourceURL: true
        },
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/neuterapp.js': '<%= yeoman.app %>/app.js'
    },
    ember_templates: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                templateName: function (sourceFile) {
                    return sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, ''); // <%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/
                }
            },
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/templates.js': [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.hbs'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use the [copy task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to prepare what usemin needs in a temporary location.

What I suggest you do:

- copy your needed app files from **app** to **temp**
- Let your tasks which generate files output to **temp**
- let your `usemin` & `useminPrepare` task run on **temp** and output to **dist**.

Comment: You can tell usemin to include more than one directory: `<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/main.js -->` will look for script files in `.tmp` and `app`.

Comment: if you can provide any JSBIN example. that would be a great help.