# Grunt - usemin always leaving dist/ directory empty

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to use the `usemin` plugin to minify and create my distributable.  Here is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    dirs: {
      dist: 'dist',
      app: 'app'
    },
    clean: {
      dist: '<%= dirs.dist %>/*'
    },
    jshint: {
      gruntfile: 'Gruntfile.js',
      sources: '<%= dirs.jshint %>',
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= dirs.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= dirs.app %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= dirs.dist %>']
      },
      html: ['<%= dirs.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= dirs.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:dist', 'jshint', 'useminPrepare', 'usemin']);
};
```

I can see my files being minified and uglified in the console, but nothing ever appears in my `dist` directory.  It is always empty.  What is the configuration that I am missing?  Also, if I am not doing anything more than what the `usemin` plugin is doing, do I need `useminPrepare` and `usemin`?

Comment: how you copy files from sources to dist?

Comment: I didn't know that I needed to copy any of the files.  I thought `usemin` would take the source files, concatenate, uglify and then drop the files in my `dest` folder.

Comment: I am just asking, I am not sure if it is necessary for some special copy rule to be there. Here is one Q [Grunt: including a generated file in usemin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922554/grunt-including-a-generated-file-in-usemin) which needed it.

Comment: One "stupid" question: do you use `--no-write` option somehow? It means: Disable writing files (dry run).

Comment: As u are using useminPrepare, it will most likely detected another directory. Please look at your console output, --verbose --debug what it sais. If all is correct, it can also be a bug in the pretty unstable grunt packages, also try to install latest npm packages.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add concat, uglify to your tasklist. Usemin will prepare config, so you don't need to do that yourself - but still need them.

ex.

grunt.registerTask('use', ['useminPrepare','usemin','concat','uglify']);